# How to shrink an ext4 partition without formatting it?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

Recently i installed Ubuntu 13.04 and allocated 20 GB for it. The system got installed space less than 10 GB. Now, can i shrink it to 10 GB without formatting it?
Thats to say, i don't want to have large empty space in the partition.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be moved, rather than just closed?

Comment: Should be moved to ServerFault

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [resize2fs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs) command.

However, I would suggest to backup the most important files (on e.g. an USB key) before doing that (e.g. `/etc/` and some of `/home/` )

See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41088) question...

BTW, 20GB for the system partition is not that much.....